# Java Concurrency in put/get in collections

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

I connect to an external service with an interactive session + a private feed (InputStream) that run on separate threads. On the interactive session, I send outgoing messages and receive synchronous responses with an object containing different fields, one being an ID and a 'status' confirming success or failure. Simultaneously I receive messages on the private feed for this ID with further 'status' updates. I currently store information about the status per ID in a ConcurrentHashMap. It is imperative that I keep a correct sequence of events on these objects but I am currently getting race conditions where I sometimes process and update the objects on the private feed before I receive and process the synchronous response on the interactive session, hence leaving me with an obsolete and incorrect status for the ID.

Ideally, I would have liked to have some type of collection with a PutIfKeyExistOrWait (w timeout) method, that would only update the value if the key exists or else wait, that I could use when processing objects on the private feed.

Does anyone know if there is a suitable collection available or can suggest an alternative solution to my problem? Thanks.

Comment: PutIfKeyExistOrWait won't help if later on (when the ID already exists) you receive 2 asynchronous notifications, but process them in the wrong order because of race conditions. It sounds like the only bulletproof way is if the incoming messages have sequence numbers. If they don't, I guess the next best thing is to attach to each message the timestamp when you received it, and then sort the statuses according to the timestamps.

Comment: @EliAcherkan Thanks. The asynchronous messages on the private feed are received in a single thread so I can 'guarantee' correct sequence of these messages. It is only the synchronous response Vs the asynchronous messages that cause problems. Timestamp doesn't work either. The messages are usually received within the same millisecond and there is no guarantee that the synchronous response is received before the messages on the private feed, hence the problem.

Comment: Sorry then, the only option I can think of is for the interactive session to have a `synchronized` block that checks whether the key was already inserted into the map by the private feed, and inserts/updates the status accordingly.

Comment: Your problem is still not clear to me.  You send a message to the service and you get back a response from the service and an "update" from the feed.  Is the ID unique like a message number? (Meaning you get one message from the service and one message from the feed with this ID.)  You are waiting for processing until you get the pair of related messages from the service and the feed?  Can you get extra messages from the feed for a given ID?

Comment: @toto2 The ID is like an order-id and I need to maintain an accurate status of the order at all times. I get one synchronous response on the interactive session and (usually) multiple status updates for the ID on the private feed. The race condition occurs for the initial interactive response Vs the private feed updates that are received simultaneously. Any subsequent updates, seconds or minutes later, on the private feed are not a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have some `ConcurrentHashMap iDAndStatus` that stores the ID and latest status.  However, I would only let the thread that deals with the service create a new entry in that map.

When a message arrives from the feed, if the ID already exists in `iDAndStatus`, it just modifies the status.  If the key does not exist, just store temporarily the ID/status updates in some other data structure, `pendingFeedUpdates`.

Everytime a new entry is created in `iDAndStatus`, check `pendingFeedUpdates` to see if some update(s) for the new ID are present.

I'm not sure what synchronized data structure to use for `pendingFeedUpdates`: you need to retrieve by ID, but you might have many messages for each ID, and you want to keep the order of the messages.  Maybe a synchronized HashMap that associates each ID with some type of synchronized ordered Queue?

Comment: Thanks. I am going with a version of your suggestion. When I process the synchronous message on the interactive session, I check if I already have a status update for the same ID from the private feed. In that case, I simply ignore the synchronous response and do not update the status. I store all messages in a separate collection to keep an order trail but I can live with a slight disarray in that list. Thanks to all for great comments and answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to encapsulate logic for handling this situation into values of your map, something like this:

- If feed thread is the first to add a value for particular id, that value is considered incomplete and thread waits until it's completed
- If interactive session thread isn't the first to add a value, it marks that incomplete value as complete
- Incomplete values are treated as absent when getting them from the map

This solution is based on atomicity of `putIfAbsent()`.

```
public class StatusMap {
    private Map<Long, StatusHolder> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<Long, StatusHolder>();

    public Status getStatus(long id) {
        StatusHolder holder = map.get(id);
        if (holder == null || holder.isIncomplete()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return holder.getStatus();
        }
    }

    public void newStatusFromInteractiveSession(long id, Status status) {
        StatusHolder holder = StatusHolder.newComplete(status);
        if ((holder = map.putIfAbsent(id, holder)) != null) {
            holder.makeComplete(status); // Holder already exists, complete it
        } 
    }

    public void newStatusFromFeed(long id, Status status) {
        StatusHolder incomplete = StatusHolder.newIncomplete();
        StatusHolder holder = null;
        if ((holder = map.putIfAbsent(id, incomplete)) == null) {
            holder = incomplete; // New holder added, wait for its completion
            holder.waitForCompletion();
        }
        holder.updateStatus(status);
    }
}

public class StatusHolder {
    private volatile Status status;
    private volatile boolean incomplete;
    private Object lock = new Object();

    private StatusHolder(Status status, boolean incomplete) { ... }

    public static StatusHolder newComplete(Status status) {
        return new StatusHolder(status, false);
    }

    public static StatusHolder newIncomplete() {
        return new StatusHolder(null, true);
    }

    public boolean isIncomplete() { return incomplete; }

    public void makeComplete(Status status) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            this.status = status;
            incomplete = false;
            lock.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    public void waitForCompletion() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            while (incomplete) lock.wait();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. +1 for the ambitious answer. Your suggestion is along the lines of what I am currently doing as a workaround where I try to workout the sequence based on source and status. There are some rather tricky scenarios involved in that mapping, e.g. in some cases there are no updates on the private feed, so I wanted to see if there was a cleaner and simpler solution that I had overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at the Collections.getSynchronized collection:http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList%28java.util.List%29

This could maybe solve you problem the other option depending how the calls are made have the method be a synchronized method that allows for thread safe execution and would ensure atomicity of transaction. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html

The third option is to enforce a concurrency management control within the application following an optimistic or pessimistic approach depending on what you are trying to achieve. This is the most complex of the 3 but will give you the greater control if coupled with the previous options.

This is really dependent on your specific implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure how ordinary synchronization or locks would solve my problem. I would still have race situations where messages on the private feed could obtain a lock before the synchronous response does. I should point out that I do not know the ID before I send my request on the interactive session, or else I could have locked the key corresponding to the ID until I had received and processed the synchronous response.

Comment: Instead of locking the record you could attempt an optimistic locking by detecting collisions and handling those collision separately http://www.agiledata.org/essays/concurrencyControl.html#OptimisticLocking  There are several ways to detect concurrent collisions my personal preference in the incremental row versions. So have the interactive send back the ID and the row version if the row version is not equal to what is in your database you have a collision and this will allow you to handle it separately.